# Django как заменить label на placeholder в форме?

Tags: python, django, form

У меня есть класс формы:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserManage
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'tel')
```

Когда я вывожу его на страницу используя: `{{ form }}`, он отображается с `label`, при этом я бы хотел добавить содержимое в атрибут `placeholder`. Как мне это сделать?

Искал, что-то типо `{{ form.as_input }}`, но не нашёл, надо делать это через **widgets**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение, сделал так:

```js
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserManage
        fields = ('username', 'password')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Логин'
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Пароль'
```

А теги `<label>` скрыл через **CSS**